# Qt Creator - how to see the code of the designer?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, signals-slots

I'm using *Qt Creator*.

I'm using the signals and slots editor, and I want to see the code it generates.

How can I see the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have in Qt Creator a form file called `widget.ui`.

Once you've compiled your project, you'll find in your project folder a filed called `ui_widget.h`.

If you open it, you'll see the code generated by the [uic](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/uic.html) tool.

Comment: Using this example, in Qt Creator, you should see the #include "ui_widget.h" line at the top of the .cpp file for your wrapper class. You can control-click that to open it.

Answer (score 0):

when you use qt creater, this one is going to create a file with the name of your project, in my case it is called "build-prueba-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_GCC_64bit-Debug", then in that file you have to look for a file with the "ui_" prefix, into that, you have the code you need