# How to see auto-generated code by QT Designer (C++)?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I used QT Designer (Qt Creator 4.0.3) and followed the tutorial described here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/gettingstartedqt.html. I managed to create a simple GUI and some signals & slots. I am able to run the application too. 
However I cannot find the corresponding code for the GUI in any of my project files. How do I find the auto generated code ? or is it generated at run-time ?

The following are screenshots of my project: 
[image: Project in Edit-mode]

[image: Project in Design mode]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt Creator - how to see the code of the designer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986140/qt-creator-how-to-see-the-code-of-the-designer)

Answer (score 2):

After you build the code in qt creator, in the build folder. there is **ui_mainwindow.h** file will cretaed will have all the generated code.

build your code then either you can verify in the folder or hold ctrl button and click on #include "ui_mainwindow.h" will open the header file